# data on US college spending

Tags: regression, paneldata, education-economics, data-sources

I am writing a research paper on college spending and profit optimization. I need data on US colleges' expenditures, revenues, and the total number of students. Since I am not from the US I am not particularly aware of where to find such databases but I assume that some researchers here will be able to provide a link to one. The more disintegrated the data- the better. I am aiming for a time series information if possible.